# eBay GetSellerTransactions & cURL_multi - limit?

Tags: ebay-api, curl-multi

Another beginners question:

I can get all eBay transactions from an item ID with GetSellerTransactions (XML).

I guess I can run cURL_multi and can get several transactions parallel. My question is, is there a limit how many item# I can send to the eBay API using cURL_multi?

Answer (score 1):

eBay allows up to 18 simultaneous threads per AppID. See [eBay Features Guide](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Call-UsingLiveData.html). This means you can fetch 18 transactions in parallel. But be aware that each single call still counts against the call limit of 5000 per day if your app hasn't passed the Compatible Application Check yet. Otherwise it will count against the 1.5 million calls per day limit.